tar: ./.tar.gz: file changed as we read it | "Flagged" files are unrelated to the file tar is supposed to operate on
I am trying to use tar to recursively compress all files with the .lammpstrj extension within the directory tree starting at the directory whose path is stored in the variable home. home contains the script containing my tar commands and 57 subdirectories, each containing a pair of sub-subdirectories named Soft_Pushoff and Equilibrium_NVT. Each Soft_Pushoff or Equilibrium_NVT directory contains one .lammpstrj file. The loop I am using to get this task done is:
for index in $(seq 1 57)
do
    cd $home/$index/Soft_Pushoff/
    file=`find ./ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "*.lammpstrj" -print`
    tar cvf - ./$file | gzip -9 - > $file.tar.gz
    cd $home/$index/Equilibration_NVT/
    file=`find ./ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "*.lammpstrj" -print`
    tar cvf - ./$file | gzip -9 - > $file.tar.gz
done

As it sweeps one of the 57 subdirectories of home, this section of the code usually prints:
././equilibration_nvt.lammpstrj
././soft_pushoff.lammpstrj

to the terminal. However, in 3 different instances, this is what this section of the code prints out:
././equilibration_nvt.lammpstrj
././soft_pushoff.lammpstrj
./
./time.txt
./soft_pushoff.restart.10000
./equilibration_nvt.lmp
./.tar.gz
tar: ./.tar.gz: file changed as we read it
./equilibration_nvt_pitzer.sh
./eps.txt
././soft_pushoff.lammpstrj
././equilibration_nvt.lammpstrj

None of the files "flagged" by tar is supposed to be operated on by the tar commands I am using, so I am confused as to why they are listed alongside the warning message tar: ./.tar.gz: file changed as we read it? Also, none of these files is actually changing as tar is operating on the .lammpstrj files. What could explain this warning message and, most importantly, can I trust that none of the .lammpstrj.tar.gz files written by my tar commands is corrupt, especially the ones associated with this warning message?
If this is relevant, my script is being run on a remote server. The .lammpstrj files I am trying to compress are up to 15.2 Gb in size. It takes about 2.5 days for my script to run on this remote server.

Your script makes no sense; not only are the find expansions unnecessary and dangerous, they also give you a newline-separated list of file names; which you then use as list of files to be compressed (that makes sense) and then again as a single file name (which makes no sense). Can you please tell us what exactly you want your output to be?

Thanks for pointing those problems out! What I am trying to do is go into each Soft_Pushoff and Equilibration_NVT directory and create an archive including the one .lammpstrj file each of those directories contains. Soft_Pushoff and Equilibration_NVT include multiple files. I am trying to find and compress the .lammpstrj file exclusively. How can I accomplish that?

what shell are you using? I ask because of multiple anachronisms in your script, which makes me suspect you're not on a modern system, potentially? If you don't know your shell, telling us your operating system as precisely as you can will probable tell us enough.

I'm using Bash. The server this script is running on operates on Linux.

this is not criticism of you, but I find it fascinating: where did you learn to write these kinds of scripts? It's an interesting, but 20 to 30 year old style!

I'm a PhD student, so I've been learning from other people's scripts and blog/forum/documentation pages. LOL!

You're honestly overcomplicating things – use your shell to get a list of matching files, and go through these.  And let's get rid of all the anachronistic things there – process substitution is usually done using $(…) instead of … these days (both safer to write and nestable!), seq begin end is superfluous when you have {begin..end}, and any tar I'm aware of has been able to apply gzip compression itself for… as long as I've been using computers, I think. So, your whole script reduces to: (replacing gzip --best with zstd -15 (15 is a very high compression setting for zstd) after our discussion above where you said compression ratio is important to you)
for file in ${home}/{1..57}/{Soft_Pushoff,Equilibration_NVT}/.lammpstrj; do
   zstd -15 "${file}"
done

You of course get better compression if you compress all files into one archive, as I suspect there's parts of them that are similar, and hence compress very well if you put them in the same archive. It's also even easier; no for loop necessary
cd home
tar -cvf - ${home}/{1..57}/{Soft_Pushoff,Equilibration_NVT}/.lammpstrj | zstd -15 -o lampstrj-archive.tar.zst


I'm sorry to bother again with this, but how do you recommend decompressing the .zst file generated by the first algorithm you suggested (the for loop one)? I found a couple of different options online, but given that I haven't always selected the best option from the ones available...

Also, .lammpstrj had to be preceded by * for the commands to work.

decompression: whatever tool supports zstd will work. How can different methods be "best" for decompression? There's no ambiguity in what you get: the uncompressed file. So, it really doesn't matter which tool you use.

Great! Thanks for helping out with this! I really appreciate it!!!

If $file is empty then you'll end up running tar cvf - ./ | gzip -9 > .tar.gz which will cause the error message you're seeing; you're tar'ing up the current directory, which will include files you're not expecting and the .tar.gz file itself will be part of the archive.
Either your find isn't doing what you expect or else you need to put a safety check around the tar
eg
if [ -n "$file" ]
then
  tar ...
fi


How do I go into each directory, find the one .lammpstrj file it contains, and compress that file only into a .lammpstrj.tar.gz archive?

@FelipeEvaristo question: why the tar if it only contains a single fle? The whole point of tar is to be a container of multiple files.

I'd understood from the page I got the command I'm using that this was a way to create the most compressed archive possible. Should I just run gzip -9 -c ./$file > $file.gz?

yes, and if you need "the most compression possible", then gzip also isn't the tool of choice.

What would you do instead, @MarcusMüller?

a) your redirection is superfluous, gzip will a compress file to file.gz anyways. b) there's other compressors; we can help you choose. Just to confirm: You need the compressed files to end up in the same directory as their originals, and not in one central archive file, nested in the same folder hierarchy within that archive?

Right, I need the compressed files to end up in the same directories as their originals. I was using the redirection because I want to preserve the originals too and not overwrite them when I apply the compressor. I understood gzip would simply replace the original file with the compressed file if I did not redirect...

@FelipeEvaristo it never replaces them; it creates a new file with .gz attached; if you call it with --keep, it keeps the original around.
